# Find records which is not following sequence in group sql

Tags: sql

I have below table

| ID | Date | Rate Type | Price | Hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18-10-2022 | R1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 18-10-2022 | R2 | 90 | 2 |
| 4 | 18-10-2022 | R4 | 120 | 4 |
| 3 | 18-10-2022 | R3 | 80 | 3 |
| 5 | 18-10-2022 | R5 | 60 | 5 |
| 6 | 18-10-2022 | R6 | 50 | 6 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 19-10-2022 | R1 | 150 | 1 |
| 8 | 19-10-2022 | R2 | 120 | 2 |
| 9 | 19-10-2022 | R3 | 200 | 3 |
| 10 | 19-10-2022 | R4 | 180 | 4 |
| 11 | 19-10-2022 | R5 | 170 | 5 |
| 12 | 19-10-2022 | R6 | 110 | 6 |

I want to filter records where prices are not going down from hierarchy 1 -> 6.

e.g. Id 4 in group 1 and Id 9,10,11 in group 2.